# Redirect output from bash script

Tags: bash, unix

I have a current bash script. `echo` will display all results when cmd has been finished. But I want in real time see output coming line by line when script is in execution process. How can I achieve that?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(docker build -t goapp -f deployments/dev/Dockerfile .)
```

Comment: `docker build -t goapp -f deployments/dev/Dockerfile . >> someFile.log` and `tail -f someFile.log` may do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker` already prints its output to standard output; that's why you can capture it with `$(...)` and pass it as arguments to `echo`. Just run `docker`:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker build -t goal -f deployments/dev/Dockerfile .
```

Comment: it stream all output if I execute that cmd manually in terminal but if I wrap it in bash .sh script it prints it only when cmd has been finished.

Comment: Are you still wrapping it in `echo $(...)`? That's the part I'm saying is unnecessary.